# I am studying basic set theory and come across with the term dense in itself.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to understand when we say a set is dense in another set and when it is dense in itself.  It is not clear in my lecture.  So please can any one of you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ordered set $A$ is called dense (in itself) if for all $a,b\in A$ with $a<b$, there exists $c\in A$ with $a<c<b$.

A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is called dense (in $X$) if every non-empty open set of $X$ contains an element of $A$. If the topoology of $X$ is the order topology, this amounts to saying that for ecvery $x,y\in X$ with $x<y$, there exists $a\in A$ with $x<a<y$.

Answer (score 1):

In a topological space $X$ $A\subset X$ is dense in $X$ if $Cl(A)=X$

for example In usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ , a subset $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R} $ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ because $Cl(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{R}$.